# Better ways to get nth element from an unsubscriptable iterable

Tags: python, iterator

Sometimes an iterable might be not subscriptable. Say the return from `itertools.permutations`:

```
ps = permutations(range(10), 10)
print ps[1000]
```

Python will complain that `'itertools.permutations' object is not subscriptable`

Of course one can perform `next()` by `n` times to get the nth element. Just wondering are there better ways to do so?

Comment: better in terms of what? efficiency or space.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just use `nth` recipe from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, islice
>>> def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
        "Returns the nth item or a default value"
        return next(islice(iterable, n, None), default)

>>> print nth(permutations(range(10), 10), 1000)
(0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 8, 9, 3, 7)
```

Comment: This is a beautiful thing. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

A more readable solution is :

```py
next(x for i,x in enumerate(ps) if i==1000)
```