# Finding Kth lexicographic permutation when repetition is allowed using Factoradic system

Tags: python, algorithm, math, permutation, factorial

Is it possible to use the [Factoradic Base System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) to find kth permutation when the repetition is allowed?

For finding Kth permutation without repetition, I can do something like this in python:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0: return 1
    return n*factorial(n-1)

def unrank(S, k, i):
    S = list(S)   # make a copy to avoid destroying the list
    n = len(S)
    nb = factorial(n) // factorial(n-k)
    print (nb)
    if i >= nb:
        raise IndexError
    res = []
    while k > 0:
        nb = nb // n
        pos = i // nb   # the factoradic digits
        i = i % nb      # the remaining digits
        res.append(S[pos])
        del S[pos]
        k = k-1
        n = n-1
    return res

res = unrank(list('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'),3, 2222)
print (res)
```

see original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956812/computing-the-nth-6-character-permutation-of-an-alphabet)

Comment: I do not understand the question. What does it mean to find the `k`th permutation "when the repetition is allowed"? Do you mean you have a list that may have repetitions in it and you want to count which permutation it is in lexicographical order of those items? And what are the meanings of `k` and `i` in your `unrank` function? Must `S` be in sorted order in that same function?

Comment: What mean about repetition allowed is that I can use the same character more than once. So if S={ABC} and k(number of chars allowed in the word ) is 3 then  this permeation is valid : AAA, AAC,ACC,BBB, etc ...

S: is the set of chars I can chose from. K: is the number of letters . i : is the permutation index the lexicographical order

Comment: So are `AAC` and `ACA` and `CAA` considered equal or different? And is `S` a set or a list, and if a list must it be unsorted?

Comment: AAC and ACA and CAA would be considered different . S is a set where  order does not matter.  it represents the allowed set of characters that you can pick from.

Answer (score 1):

Just write the number out in base `|S|` (that is, the size if the set of possible letters). Use the elements of the set in (some) order as the "digits".

As an example consider the sequence of lists of three elements from `list('0123456789')`. Observe that it is precisely the numbers from 0 to 999, written with leading zeros if necessary to make them three digits long.

**Update**

Here is some Python code that illustrates the idea:

```
def unrank(src, reqlen, pos):
    size = len(src)
    # it is easier to fill result from the end, so pre-create an array of the required size
    res = [src[0]] * reqlen
    for i in xrange(reqlen - 1, -1, -1):
        res[i] = src[pos % size]
        pos /= size
    if pos > 0: # this means original pos was beyond (size ** reqlen) i.e. more than the max possible index
        raise IndexError
    return res

res = unrank(list('0123456789ABCDEF'), 3, 2222)
print (res)
```

which prints

> ['8', 'A', 'E']

You can easily check that hex value of `0x8AE` is actually `2222`.

Comment: Rici, I took liberty to extend your answer with some code. Feel free to edit it any way you like.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** No, I do not see a way to use the Factoradic Base System to do what you want, but there is an easier way to do that. Just use something like the usual number bases.

Your terminology is confusing, since you write of "permutations" but allow repetition. Let's call them sequences instead, where the function is given a test sequence to examine and the base sequence which holds the characters which can be used. You want to find the count of the test sequence in the lexicographical listing of all possible sequences of the same length using the characters in the base sequence.

For convenience let's assume that the base sequence is in increasing order and has no repetitions, as in your example code.

For each character in the sequence we want to know where it occurs in the base sequence. If the base sequence and the sequence are both long the simple way to do this could be time consuming, of order the product of the lengths. There is a way to do this with order the sum of the lengths: First pre-process the base sequence to get a dictionary that maps each character to its position in the base sequence, then convert each character in our test sequence to its position in the base sequence. We now have a list of character positions in the base sequence.

This list is like a base-N number, where N is the length of the base sequence. We then do the usual methods to convert this to a standard integer, which is our desired result.

Here is some code to do all this. There are, of course, other ways to do this.

```
def sequence_position(test_seq, base_seq):
    """Return the count of the test sequence in the lexicographical
    listing of all possible sequences of the same length using the 
    items in the base sequence. Repetition of items is allowed and the 
    order of the items in the list matters.

    This function assumes the base sequence is in increasing order and
    has no repetitions.
    """
    # Create a dictionary mapping items in the base sequence to
    #   their positions in the base sequence.
    item_pos_dict = {item:pos for pos,item in enumerate(base_seq)}
    # Create a list of positions of the characters in the test sequence.
    positions = [item_pos_dict[item] for item in test_seq]
    # Convert this list of positions to its count in the lexicographical
    #   sequence of all such sequences of this length
    base = len(base_seq)
    result = 0
    for pos in positions:
        result = result * base + pos
    return result

print(sequence_position('ABC', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'))
```