# How to get permutations from factoradic numbers without lambda as a array formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, permutation, factorial

##### Data:

###### Input#1(C1):

```
0,1,2
```

| (A1)Input#2 | Expected Output |
| --- | --- |
| 0:0:0 | 0,1,2 |
| 0:1:0 | 0,2,1 |
| 1:0:0 | 1,0,2 |
| 1:1:0 | 1,2,0 |
| 2:0:0 | 2,0,1 |
| 2:1:0 | 2,1,0 |

Sample for `0,1,2,3,4` below:

```html
For Input#1(C1): 0,1,2,3,4    
(A1)Input#2    Output
0:0:0:0:0   0,1,2,3,4
0:0:0:1:0   0,1,2,4,3
0:0:1:0:0   0,1,3,2,4
0:0:1:1:0   0,1,3,4,2
0:0:2:0:0   0,1,4,2,3
0:0:2:1:0   0,1,4,3,2
0:1:0:0:0   0,2,1,3,4
0:1:0:1:0   0,2,1,4,3
0:1:1:0:0   0,2,3,1,4
0:1:1:1:0   0,2,3,4,1
0:1:2:0:0   0,2,4,1,3
0:1:2:1:0   0,2,4,3,1
0:2:0:0:0   0,3,1,2,4
0:2:0:1:0   0,3,1,4,2
0:2:1:0:0   0,3,2,1,4
0:2:1:1:0   0,3,2,4,1
0:2:2:0:0   0,3,4,1,2
0:2:2:1:0   0,3,4,2,1
0:3:0:0:0   0,4,1,2,3
0:3:0:1:0   0,4,1,3,2
0:3:1:0:0   0,4,2,1,3
0:3:1:1:0   0,4,2,3,1
0:3:2:0:0   0,4,3,1,2
0:3:2:1:0   0,4,3,2,1
1:0:0:0:0   1,0,2,3,4
1:0:0:1:0   1,0,2,4,3
1:0:1:0:0   1,0,3,2,4
1:0:1:1:0   1,0,3,4,2
1:0:2:0:0   1,0,4,2,3
1:0:2:1:0   1,0,4,3,2
1:1:0:0:0   1,2,0,3,4
1:1:0:1:0   1,2,0,4,3
1:1:1:0:0   1,2,3,0,4
1:1:1:1:0   1,2,3,4,0
1:1:2:0:0   1,2,4,0,3
1:1:2:1:0   1,2,4,3,0
1:2:0:0:0   1,3,0,2,4
1:2:0:1:0   1,3,0,4,2
1:2:1:0:0   1,3,2,0,4
1:2:1:1:0   1,3,2,4,0
1:2:2:0:0   1,3,4,0,2
1:2:2:1:0   1,3,4,2,0
1:3:0:0:0   1,4,0,2,3
1:3:0:1:0   1,4,0,3,2
1:3:1:0:0   1,4,2,0,3
1:3:1:1:0   1,4,2,3,0
1:3:2:0:0   1,4,3,0,2
1:3:2:1:0   1,4,3,2,0
2:0:0:0:0   2,0,1,3,4
2:0:0:1:0   2,0,1,4,3
2:0:1:0:0   2,0,3,1,4
2:0:1:1:0   2,0,3,4,1
2:0:2:0:0   2,0,4,1,3
2:0:2:1:0   2,0,4,3,1
2:1:0:0:0   2,1,0,3,4
2:1:0:1:0   2,1,0,4,3
2:1:1:0:0   2,1,3,0,4
2:1:1:1:0   2,1,3,4,0
2:1:2:0:0   2,1,4,0,3
2:1:2:1:0   2,1,4,3,0
2:2:0:0:0   2,3,0,1,4
2:2:0:1:0   2,3,0,4,1
2:2:1:0:0   2,3,1,0,4
2:2:1:1:0   2,3,1,4,0
2:2:2:0:0   2,3,4,0,1
2:2:2:1:0   2,3,4,1,0
2:3:0:0:0   2,4,0,1,3
2:3:1:1:0   2,4,1,3,0
2:3:2:0:0   2,4,3,0,1
2:3:2:1:0   2,4,3,1,0
3:0:0:0:0   3,0,1,2,4
3:0:0:1:0   3,0,1,4,2
3:0:1:0:0   3,0,2,1,4
3:0:1:1:0   3,0,2,4,1
3:0:2:0:0   3,0,4,1,2
3:0:2:1:0   3,0,4,2,1
3:1:0:0:0   3,1,0,2,4
3:1:0:1:0   3,1,0,4,2
3:1:2:1:0   3,1,4,2,0
3:2:0:0:0   3,2,0,1,4
3:2:0:1:0   3,2,0,4,1
3:2:1:0:0   3,2,1,0,4
3:2:1:1:0   3,2,1,4,0
3:2:2:0:0   3,2,4,0,1
3:2:2:1:0   3,2,4,1,0
3:3:0:0:0   3,4,0,1,2
3:3:0:1:0   3,4,0,2,1
3:3:1:0:0   3,4,1,0,2
3:3:1:1:0   3,4,1,2,0
3:3:2:0:0   3,4,2,0,1
3:3:2:1:0   3,4,2,1,0
4:0:0:0:0   4,0,1,2,3
4:0:0:1:0   4,0,1,3,2
4:0:1:0:0   4,0,2,1,3
4:0:1:1:0   4,0,2,3,1
4:0:2:0:0   4,0,3,1,2
4:0:2:1:0   4,0,3,2,1
4:1:0:0:0   4,1,0,2,3
4:1:0:1:0   4,1,0,3,2
4:1:1:0:0   4,1,2,0,3
4:1:1:1:0   4,1,2,3,0
4:1:2:0:0   4,1,3,0,2
4:1:2:1:0   4,1,3,2,0
4:2:0:0:0   4,2,0,1,3
4:2:0:1:0   4,2,0,3,1
4:2:1:0:0   4,2,1,0,3
4:2:1:1:0   4,2,1,3,0
4:2:2:0:0   4,2,3,0,1
4:2:2:1:0   4,2,3,1,0
4:3:0:0:0   4,3,0,1,2
4:3:0:1:0   4,3,0,2,1
4:3:1:0:0   4,3,1,0,2
4:3:1:1:0   4,3,1,2,0
4:3:2:0:0   4,3,2,0,1
4:3:2:1:0   4,3,2,1,0
```

##### Constrains:

- **No lambda functions or their helpers**, including but not limited to `REDUCE`,`MAP`,etc. Named functions **without** lambda/lambda helper functions are allowed.
- No brute forcing. Need a [dry](/questions/tagged/dry), scalable solution. For eg, I might need a corresponding permutation for "5:4:0:0:0:1:0" for input#1 of `0,1,2,3,4,5,6`
- Must be `ARRAYFORMULA` solution in `B2`, which will fill all of `B2:B` for corresponding `A2:A`(no `BYROW`)
- No workarounds. It maybe be a XY problem. I still need to solve `Y`, and not `X`.
- Should go without saying, but No scripts
- Should be able to handle <sub>8</sub>P<sub>8</sub>(40320)factoradic numbers without issues
- Recursion allowed. Turning on Iterative calculation not allowed.

##### Explanation:

Indexes start from `0` instead of `1`. For `Input#1`, `0,1,2`,
For `A2`, `0:0:0`, for the first `0`, remove 0th element `0`. The remaining array is `1,2`. For the second 0, remove 0th element `1` from the remaining `1,2`. For the third `0`, remove 0th element `2`. The final result `0,1,2` for `0:0:0`. For `0:1:0`:

| index(from input#2) | remaining input#1 | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0,1,2 ^ ^ ^ **[0]**,1,2 <<< Index | 0 |
| 1 | 1,2 ^ ^ 0,**[1]** <<< Index | 2 |
| 0 | 1 ^ **[0]** <<< Index | 1 |

##### What can be assumed:

- Input#1 will always be ascending sequence.
- Length of input#1 will be equal to length of each of input#2

##### What cannot be assumed:

- Number of elements will always be 3. No it may be so much more.

##### What have I tried?

Many things for days. The closest I got was a direct approach. But it's inefficient and most importantly, doesn't support arrays. I did it with named functions. Note the order of arguments matter. For eg, in `SPLICE`, the first argument should be a `arr`, then `i` and then `j`, exactly in that order as shown above.

##### `SHIFT(arr)`

- Description:

  - Removes first element in a array
- Arguments:

  - `arr` A vertical array to remove the first element eg: `{1;2;3}`
- Formula definition:

```
=FILTER(arr,{0;SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr)-1)})
```

- Example:

`=SHIFT({1;2;3})` returns `{2;3}`

##### `SPLICE(arr,i,j)`

- Description:

  - Removes a part of the array.
- Arguments(in order):

  - `arr` A vertical array
  - `i`   Starting index to splice(inclusive)
  - `j`   Ending index to splice(exclusive)
- Formula definition:

```
=FILTER(arr,LAMBDA(seq,(seq<i)+(seq>=j))(SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr))))
```

- Example:

  - `=SPLICE({1;2;3;4;5},2,4)` removes second to the fourth element. Returns `{1;4;5}`

##### `FACTTOPERM(inparr,factarr)`

- Description:

  - Returns corresponding permutation from factorial.
- Arguments(in order):

  - `inparr`    Vertical input array (Eg: `{0;1;2}`)
  - `factarr`   Vertical Factorial array+1 (Eg: `{0;1;0}+1`)
- Formula definition:

```
=IF(ISERROR(JOIN(,inparr)),,INDEX(inparr,INDEX(factarr,1))&FACTTOPERM(SPLICE(inparr,INDEX(factarr,1),INDEX(factarr,1)+1),SHIFT(factarr)))
```

- Example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FACTTOPERM({0;1;2},{0;1;0}+1))
```

will give `021`, because as seen in the above table, `0:1:0`  corresponds to `0,2,1`.

I can use `BYROW` to call it repeatedly, but it quickly hits lambda  limitations. Here's how I used `BYROW` to call it:

| (A1)Input#2 | Output | 0,1,2 | Formula in C column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0:0:0 | 0,1,2 | 012 | =ARRAYFORMULA(BYROW(A2:A7,LAMBDA(row, FACTTOPERM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C1,",")),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(row,":")+1))))) |
| 0:1:0 | 0,2,1 | 021 |  |
| 1:0:0 | 1,0,2 | 102 |  |
| 1:1:0 | 1,2,0 | 120 |  |
| 2:0:0 | 2,0,1 | 201 |  |
| 2:1:0 | 2,1,0 | 210 |  |

#### References:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1400468

Comment: Backgrounder: [Factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Permutations), [Lehmer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code).

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster Is there an online tool that handles the input you demonstrated?

Comment: @Osm My formula in the question will give accurate results, if provided a vertical array. But this algorithm is fairly easy to implement in apps script or basically any language(like python- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740459/finding-kth-lexicographic-permutation-when-repetition-is-allowed-using-factoradi )

Comment: @Osm [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factoradic+form+of+the+permutation+%283+1+2+5+4%29) does the reverse.

Comment: is this somehow related to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73752135/5632629 ?

Comment: @player0 Yes. The rabbit hole started there. Why do you ask?

Comment: I did have a breakthrough with this recently :)

Comment: @TheMaster I just noticed some similarities

Comment: You really noticed the similarities :D between [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73752135/19529694) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74045896/19529694) and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74101502/19529694) :D there is a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74101502/get-a-match-when-there-are-duplicate-letters-in-a-string/74101561?noredirect=1#comment130936043_74101561) indeed this is what we've been doing the entire time. @player0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the question is to avoid iteration and use vectorized methods(similar to such methods used in [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)) to support array formulas. The  hardest problem here is how to vectorize parsing the lehmer code.

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |

If you remove  the middle element `1`, we get,

| 0 | 2 |
| --- | --- |

Say, we want to take element with index `1`, in the first array, that refers to the second element(index starting at 0). But after removing `1`(with index `1`) from the array, the same index `1`, now refers to `2`. Now, we can't just take stuff from a array in [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) and have a formula as array-formula. If we take `1` from  the first row, we have to take it from all rows. And other rows might not have the same element to take from. Therefore, vectorization is lost, if we attempt removal. The question itself shows a non-vectorized operation working well.

Fortunately, there is a magic formula which solves the entire  problem. That is `IF`. So, what we want is index `1` to refer to value `1`. But, if we do this again, it needs to refer to the value `2`. Take the opposite end of the spectrum. If we want index `0`, that should stay the same even after index `1` is removed. In other words, every index to the right to the array, where we took a element, is to be reduced by `1`, but every index to the  left of it shouldn't have their index changed. The `IF` can be written like this:

```
=IF(elementTaken<=arr,arr-1,arr)
```

What this does is, it actually creates 2 arrays first:

`arr-1`:

| -1 | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |

`arr`(unchanged):

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |

Here, `IF` does it's magic, merging both arrays to a single one based on the `elementTaken`. If the element taken is `1`, the final array is:

| 0 arr | 0 arr-1 | 1 arr-1 |
| --- | --- | --- |

This array is beautiful. We have  first `0` at the right index `0` and first `1` at the right index `2`. Now, all we have to do is provide vertical arrays as `elementTaken`. The `Input#2`, when `split` looks like,

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |

If we  provide the first column to `IF`, we get a merged array like this for `0, 1, 2`:

First Col as `elementTaken`(say `inp`ut `Arr`ay),

| Col1 |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

A resulting merged array from `IF`. Let's call this `comp`arision`Arr`ay

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 0 | 1 |
| -1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |

Now,  since the indexes are all in the correct place. All we have to do is compare the next array(`Col2`) against the `comp`arision `arr`ay.

| Col2 |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 1 |

```
=IF(Col2=comparisionArray created previously, {0,1,2},)
```

This creates the result we need for the second array:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 |  |
|  |  | 2 |
| 0 | 1 |  |
|  |  | 2 |
| 0 |  |  |
|  | 1 | 2 |

If we take the first element in each of those, we have the corresponding  `res`ult `Array`:

| ResArr(for Col2) |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 0 |
| 1 |

If we keep repeating this  using recursion, we get 1 column for each recursion as a array formula.

##### Helper function:

`DROP(rng, to_drop)`:

```
=FILTER(rng,
  ISNA(MATCH(SEQUENCE(
    IF(ROWS(to_drop)>COLUMNS(to_drop),ROWS(rng),1),
    IF(ROWS(to_drop)>COLUMNS(to_drop),1,COLUMNS(rng))
  ),to_drop,0))
)
```

A function to drop columns as needed.

##### Main function

`PERM_FROM_FACT(inpArr,compArr,resArr,limit)`:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    AND(ISNA(inpArr)),
    resArr,
    DROP(
      {
        IF(AND(resArr=""),INDEX(inpArr,0,1),resArr),
        PERM_FROM_FACT(
          DROP(inpArr,{1}),
          IF(
            INDEX(inpArr,0,1)<=compArr,
            compArr-1,
            compArr
          ),
          --REGEXEXTRACT(
            " "&TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
              IF(
                INDEX(inpArr,0,1)=compArr,
                SEQUENCE(1,limit,0),
              )
            ),,9^99)),
            "^\s*(\d+)"
          ),
          limit
        )
      },
      IF(AND(resArr=""),{1},{0})
    )
  )
)
```

##### Usage:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PERM_FROM_FACT(SPLIT(A2:A8,":"),SPLIT(C1,","),,3))
```

###### Output:

| Input#2 | Expected Output | 0,1,2 | D1 | E1 | F1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0:0:0 | 0,1,2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | =ARRAYFORMULA(PERM_FROM_FACT(SPLIT(A2:A8,":"),SPLIT(C1,","),,3)) |
| 0:1:0 | 0,2,1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 1:0:0 | 1,0,2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |  |
| 1:1:0 | 1,2,0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |  |
| 2:0:0 | 2,0,1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |  |
| 2:1:0 | 2,1,0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |  |

We can `join` byrow if needed using `QUERY(,, unlimited headers)`. I was hoping to avoid string manipulation or query hacks, but it was(seemed) impossible to get the first item per row in the comparison array without merging by row using `query`. So, it's used already. Since the values are basically indexes, you can use the resulting array to lookup any other array with `HLOOKUP`(or VLOOKUP) using key range as `{SEQUENCE(3);keyArray}` to get different permutations.

I was able to get 40k(8 item permutation) rows easily, which was [not possible with DRY formulas known to human kind before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73765831/). I wasn't able to see <sub>9</sub>P<sub>9</sub>(300,000+) permutations in my system, within a reasonable time. Nevertheless, this is a beautiful solution crafted elegantly, with special attention to detail, memory size and number of operations.