# How to create a sequence of numbers with repeat and increment at intervals in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence, repeat

I need a single cell formula to create a sequence of numbers with a limit in Google Sheets as shown in the image.

3 rows repeat the value

then Increment by 5

[image]

Comment: picture not showing for me

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula, you can adjust the [**`Sequence()`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) and [**`REPT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134)`(rg&",",3)` parameters to your need.

In this example [**`Sequence`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)`(number_of_unique_numbers,columns,start_at,increment_by)`

And [**`REPT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134)`(rg&",",Repeat_N_times)`

```
=ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(SPLIT(BYROW(SEQUENCE(3,1,5,5), 
 LAMBDA(rg, IF(rg="",,REPT(rg&",",3)))),",")))
```

[image]

**Option 02**
Based on [Themaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74078052/19529694) we use lambda with the names.
`u` unique
 `s` start
 `r` repat n time

```
=LAMBDA(u,s,r, FLATTEN(MAKEARRAY(u,r,LAMBDA(u,r,u*s))))
       (4,5,3)
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`FLATTEN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) - [**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) - [**`SEQUENCE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`REPT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134) - [**`MAKEARRAY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569202)

Answer (score 3):

Use `MAKEARRAY` with `FLATTEN`. Multiply the row index number by 5:

```
=FLATTEN(MAKEARRAY(4,3,LAMBDA(i,j,i*5)))
```

| Output |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 5 |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 10 |
| 10 |
| 15 |
| 15 |
| 15 |
| 20 |
| 20 |
| 20 |

Comment: Can i steal and refactor? @themaster

Comment: Because I did thought about `MAKEARRAY` and did't spend time to solve it. and your answer is the quickest shortcut to the perfect non named function solution.

Comment: @Osm As long as you give credit, go for it. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: @Osm Yes, I was wondering what refactor could be shorter than this. Do you actually have a shorter method or a method with less number of operations? PS: I did upvote your answer for adding explanations. So, can't upvote anymore, if you do show something.

Comment: I can take bounty :) @Themaster

Comment: @Osm If you satisfactorily answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74045896/how-to-get-permutations-from-factoradic-numbers-without-lambda-as-a-array-formul), bounty is yours :)

Comment: @TheMaster atOsm. You guys are awesome.  All your solutions works fine even though i did not understand a thing. But there is a small catch. In my case, limit is the number of rows. if my limit is 7, then it should  be like
5
5
5
5 5
10  
10  .
Can you guys please make that possible? I am sure you can. ;)

Comment: @anwwwar Kindly ask new question for any follow up question. Also research before asking. In this case, look into `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`. If you're unable to figure it out, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(4, 1, 5, 5)*SEQUENCE(1, 3, 1, 0)))
```

[image: 2]

or:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(5*MAKEARRAY(4, 3, LAMBDA(x, O ,x))))
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, but probably not a good one...:

```
=arrayformula(mround(sequence(12,1,2),3)*(5/3))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.