# Get specific permutation without evaluating the full iterator (itertools.permutation)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-itertools

I want to access few fixed samples for a permutation of a long list. Obviously I can do:

```
In [18]: import itertools

In [19]: l = [p for p in itertools.permutations(range(10))]

In [20]: len(l)
Out[20]: 3628800

In [21]: l[256766]
Out[21]: (0, 7, 3, 9, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 8)
```

But this causes the long list `l` to be evaluated for the list creation. Still possible for 10 items list. Hangs for larger lists.

Is there a way to get a specific permutation by calling its number without creating the full list?

Please note that I don't want to access a random shuffle. I want it to be the same permutation, preferable with the "permutation number" matching the list position called when using itertools.permutations.

**Edit:** Re: duplication. Answers related to the itertools modules are also welcomed (see the discussion below). So while goal is the same as in [Ranking and unranking of permutations with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884708/ranking-and-unranking-of-permutations-with-duplicates) the discussion in itertools context might still be worthwhile.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007820/better-ways-to-get-nth-element-from-an-unsubscriptable-iterable

Comment: @zondo The islice method is cool, but it needs resetting the iterator after every call, doesn't it? Subsequent calls seems to return different results...

Comment: Yes.  I'll see if I can come up with a solution that remembers the values that have already been generated.  What Python version are you using?

Comment: @zondo Using python3

Comment: Well, I made it compatible with Python 2 and 3.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not too difficult:

```
def nthperm(l, n):
    l = list(l)

    indices = []
    for i in xrange(1, 1+len(l)):
        indices.append(n % i)
        n //= i
    indices.reverse()

    perm = []
    for index in indices:
        # Using pop is kind of inefficient. We could probably avoid it.
        perm.append(l.pop(index))
    return tuple(perm)
```

The idea here is that the `n`th permutation of a list `l` starts with item `n // factorial(len(l) - 1)` and continues with the `n % factorial(len(l) - 1)`th permutation of the remaining elements of `l`.

If you test it, you'll find it does work:

```
>>> all(perm == nthperm(range(5), i) for i, perm in enumerate(itertools.permutations(range(5))))
True
```

And it works quickly enough for inputs where iterating through `itertools.permutations` would never finish:

```
>>> nthperm(range(100), factorial(100) // 2)
(50, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 2
1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 4
1, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 6
2, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 8
2, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.islice()`:

```
def get(perms, index):
    return next(itertools.islice(perms, index, index+1))
```

Note that this will partially exhaust the iterator.  That means that you can't do it more than once on the same iterator.

---

You can also create your own class so that it can remember what values have already been generated.  That way, you can find more than one index on the same object:

```
class Perms:
    def __init__(self, iterable, r=None):
        self.perm = itertools.permutations(iterable, r)
        self.generated = []

        self.next = self.__next__ # Python 2 compatibility

    def __next__(self):
        value = next(self.perm)
        self.generated.append(value)
        return value

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index < 0:
            self.generated.extend(self.perm)
        else:
            gen_length = len(self.generated)
            for _ in range(index - gen_length + 1): 
                next(self)

        return self.generated[index]
```

Comment: For large index number the __getitem__ is slow. It iterates over the iterator till the right index number.