# Getting Nth permutation of a sequence and getting back original using its index and modified sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I know the most popular permutation algorithms (thanks to wonderful question/answer on SO, and other related sites, such as Wikipedia, etc), but I recently wanted to see if I could get the Nth permutation without exhausting the whole permutation space.

Factorial comes to mind, so I ended up looking at posts such as [this one that implements the unrank and rank algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114883/i-give-you-nth-permutation-you-give-me-n/115024#115024%5D), as well as [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884708/ranking-and-unranking-of-permutations-with-duplicates), [many](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations/Rank_of_a_permutation) other ones. (Here as mentioned, I take into account other sites as "post")

I stumbled upon [this ActiveState recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/126037-getting-nth-permutation-of-a-sequence/) which seems like it fit what I wanted to do, but it doesn't support doing the reverse (using the result of the function and reusing the index to get back the original sequence/order).

I also found a similar and related answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38166666/12349101

But the same problem as above.

I tried and made different versions of the unrank/rank implementation(s) above, but they require that the sorted sequence be passed as well as the index given by the rank function. If a random (even within the range of the total permutation count) is given, it won't work (most of the time I tried at least).

I don't know how to implement this and I don't think I saw anyone on SO doing this yet. Is there any existing algorithm or way to do this/approach this?

*To make things clearer*:

Here is the Activestate recipe I posted above (at least the one posted in the comment):

```
from functools import reduce
def NPerms (seq):
    "computes the factorial of the length of "
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range (1, len (seq) + 1), 1)

def PermN (seq, index):
    "Returns the th permutation of  (in proper order)"
    seqc = list (seq [:])
    result = []
    fact = NPerms (seq)
    index %= fact
    while seqc:
        fact = fact // len (seqc)
        choice, index = index // fact, index % fact
        result += [seqc.pop (choice)]
    return result
```

As mentioned, this handles doing part of what I mentioned in the title, but I don't know how to get back the original sequence/order using both the result of that function + the same index used.

Say I use the above on a string such as `hello world` inside a list:

```
print(PermN(list("hello world"), 20))
```

This output: `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'd', 'r', 'o', 'l']`
Now to see if this can go back to the original using the same index + result of the above:

```
print(PermN(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'd', 'r', 'o', 'l'], 20))
```

Output: `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'l', 'r', 'd', 'o']`

Comment: feel free to give feedback in the comments for the quality of the question/title/etc. I feel like I could have made the title a bit better but not sure.

Comment: It isn't clear (at least to me) what you are trying to accomplish, much less how.  Maybe an example or 2, or posting one of your attempts, would help.

Comment: the closest to what I want to do is what the linked ActiveState recipe is doing. I'll post the snippet in my post shortly :) @ScottHunter

Comment: Just finished editing, feel free to give feedback :) I can also post what I tried with the unrank/rank algorithm, but since it has a lot more code, I refrained from doing that (don't want to make my post too big) @ScottHunter

Comment: So if your list of permutations was `lp=["123","132","213","231","321","312"]`, what would you expect `PermN("231",2)` to return: `"132"` or `"312"`, and why?

Comment: I'm not expecting that (I see what you mean and that makes sense), but instead, I'm asking how to do the reverse of what the code I posted does, to get back the original order using the same index (as I showed in my example) @ScottHunter

Comment: If you are looking for a *different* function to go back to the original, you should start by giving it a different name.

Comment: I mean, I did mention I used the same code from the ActiveState recipe...as you can see, I'm not sure how to approach this, which is why I ask. Sorry if it seems like I'm not giving enough information/research :/ @ScottHunter

Comment: can anyone tell me what more details/clarity can I add to make this question better? I think what I said makes sense and is detailed enough, but if not, any clarification is welcome. (I'm asking since I saw *someone* voted to close this, which I don't mind, but that's beside the point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want, and has the benefit that it doesn't matter what the algorithm behind `PermN` is:

```
def NmreP(seq,index):
    # Copied from PermN
    seqc = list (seq [:])
    result = []
    fact = NPerms (seq)
    index %= fact
    
    seq2 = list(range(len(seq))) # Make a list of seq indices
    fwd = PermN(seq2,index)      # Arrange them as PermN would
    result = [0]*len(seqc)       # Make an array to fill with results
    for i,j in enumerate(fwd):   # For each position, find the element in seqc in the position this started from
        result[j] = seqc[i]
    return result
```

Comment: Don't sound so surprised :)

Comment: But I can't help but be surprised...I spent a lot of time trying to find a solution by myself :) I think a couple of days on and off, or so. I know it's a bit much for fulfilling some curiosity, but still.