# create different shuffled copies of list / array

Tags: python, random, shuffle

The deal is you have a python list, or an array, (actually I intend this for the rows of a dataframe, but I guess there are better chances for it to work on a list / array)

you want to create n copies of the said list with the order of the included objects shuffled (permutations) e.g.
   `original = [ 5, 10, 15, 20] copy1 = [5, 15, 20, 10] copy2 = [10, 15, 20, 5] copy3 = [10, 20, 5, 15]`

it's an easy feat to shuffle the order of the objects, but here is the catch: you want to make sure no 2 copies created are the same.

the "easy" way would be to create random shuffled lists, append every copy created in a list and for every new copy have it checked across all the previous "approved" copies and if it's a new one then "approve" it and add it to the list but if it is same with one of the previous random copies then discard it and have a new random copy created.

that could work for small number of objects in the list, but as the objects increase so does the length of the list containing the copies (essentially the maximum n is the factorial of the length of the original) and a for-loop that would do the checking every time would be very time consuming, so I am checking if there could be some way to "predict" that the random permutation is not fully random (and thus prone to being randomly the same). Perhaps set_state and get_state could help? I am way out of my league here...

**Resolution after feedback**
Thanks for the help people, here is what I will do:
Since the permutations of the original list are going to be used as input for a Monte-Carlo type analysis, I estimate I do not need more than 300 permutations.
So, I will split the code in 2, if len(data) <= 5 i will be using permutations from itertool (5! = 120), if n>5 I will just pick 300 random permutations because the chance of 2 of them being the same is too small, plus it won't make an impact (the simulation results of all permutations are averaged in the end, so such an event would have a minimal impact over a sum of 300 results).
Cheers

Comment: How long is your list and how large is n?

Comment: *"to "predict" that the random permutation is not fully random (and thus prone to being randomly the same)."* If there was no chance of getting a repeat, the process would not be random. A fully random process always has the chance of repeating items (just like if you toss a coin and find a head, the probability of a head on the next throw is 50%). How big the probability is depends on how many items you have and how many permutations you want.

Comment: How different do the shuffles need to be? For example, if you ensure that the 42nd element of every shuffle is different then you have guaranteed unique shuffles, but other parts of the shuffles might be very similar.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function from `itertools` library.

```py
from itertools import permutations

data = [5, 10, 15, 20]

per = list(permutations(data))
print("Length of per: ", len(per), "\n")
print(per)
```

**Output:**

```
Length of per:  24     # which is indeed equals to 4!

[(5, 10, 15, 20), (5, 10, 20, 15), (5, 15, 10, 20), (5, 15, 20, 10), 
(5, 20, 10, 15), (5, 20, 15, 10), (10, 5, 15, 20), (10, 5, 20, 15), 
(10, 15, 5, 20), (10, 15, 20, 5), (10, 20, 5, 15), (10, 20, 15, 5), 
(15, 5, 10, 20), (15, 5, 20, 10), (15, 10, 5, 20), (15, 10, 20, 5), 
(15, 20, 5, 10), (15, 20, 10, 5), (20, 5, 10, 15), (20, 5, 15, 10), 
(20, 10, 5, 15), (20, 10, 15, 5), (20, 15, 5, 10), (20, 15, 10, 5)]
```

Or, you can hard code all this stuff. It may not be as efficient as the built-in function, but you can try it. So, in this case, we need to use a [**recursive function**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9/) to achieve this. Here's how we can do it:

```py
data = [5, 10, 15, 20]


def permutations(array: list) -> list:
    mutated_copies = []
    length = len(array)

    # If there is only one element in the array, then there is no point to
    # mutate the list since there is only one permutation is possible. So,
    # just simply append it to the mutated_copies and return it.
    if length == 1:
        mutated_copies.append(array)

    else:
        for i in range(length):
            # Grab the ith element of the array.
            element = array[i]

            # array[:i] means everything until the ith element and
            # array[i + 1:] means everything after the ith element. Which
            # simply implies that extracting the ith element from the array
            # and storing the remaining
            remaining = array[:i] + array[i + 1:]

            # Generating all permutations with the help of recursion. Permute
            # the remaining array until i reaches to the end of the array and
            # break out of the recursion.
            for p in permutations(remaining):
                # Here, p is each permutation of permutations of remaining.

                mutated_copies.append([element] + p)

                # Here, we are concatenating two lists. "element" is a single
                # value which is stored inside of an array/list and p is
                # another list/array. And in Python you can add two
                # arrays/lists with just the "+" operator.

    return mutated_copies


per = permutations(data)
print("Length of per: ", len(per), "\n")
print(per)
```

**Output:**

```
Length of per:  24          # which is also equals to 4!

[[5, 10, 15, 20], [5, 10, 20, 15], [5, 15, 10, 20], [5, 15, 20, 10],
[5, 20, 10, 15], [5, 20, 15, 10], [10, 5, 15, 20], [10, 5, 20, 15],
[10, 15, 5, 20], [10, 15, 20, 5], [10, 20, 5, 15], [10, 20, 15, 5],
[15, 5, 10, 20], [15, 5, 20, 10], [15, 10, 5, 20], [15, 10, 20, 5],
[15, 20, 5, 10], [15, 20, 10, 5], [20, 5, 10, 15], [20, 5, 15, 10], 
[20, 10, 5, 15], [20, 10, 15, 5], [20, 15, 5, 10], [20, 15, 10, 5]]
```

To visualize this whole process, you can use a debugging tool where you can actually see what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe adding a new unique is what `set` would be useful for. It will compare using a hash, and shouldn't grow as poorly for larger lists

```py
from random import shuffle

n = 3
original = [ 5, 10, 15, 20]
result = set()

result.add(tuple(original))  # if you also don't want copies to be different to the original
x = original.copy()
while len(result) < (n+1):  # +1 to include the original
    shuffle(x)
    result.add(tuple(x))
```

for smaller `n` then I would expect this not be be too bad

If your list if large, then there are so many permutations you will only ever have space to store a tiny subset of them so i would basically never expect to hit any duplicates.

Comment: You could do `x = original.copy()` just once outside the loop here, because `tuple(x)` copies all the elements, so mutating `x` won't change the contents of the set.

Answer (score 0):

As an idea you can use pre-determined permutations from itertools, which will give you an iterable https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Then generate random indices of the permutations you want to choose, sort them, get according permutations like this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12007859/22052558

Then shuffle them again.

Comment: For this to be random, it will have to do even more work than the approach suggested by the OP. The only way to get to any random permutation this way is to generate all the ones that come before it and that will be impossible if the original list gets long.

Comment: @user2390182 Whether it's more work depends on the sizes. Could also be much less.